# Custom Redirect url in Azure integration

Tags: android, azure

I am creating an app in which i am integrating Azure so for this i have register the app in Active Directory,but i am not getting what to pass in redirect url,Can i pass my custom url as a redirect url.and how to handle this custom url means api.?

```
authenticationContext.acquireToken(LoginActivity.this,Constant.RESOURCE_ID
            Constant.CLIENT_ID, Constant.REDIRECT_URL, "", PromptBehavior.Auto, "",
            callback);
```

If here i'll pass my api in Redirecturl so for this how i'll handle api response,and where i'll call my server using Aquery?
I have to do something in call back?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to read about OAuth 2 flow works with Azure AD.

When you register an *AD app* , the redirect uri is the endpoint url of your application where AD will send the response back post authentication.

For a mobile device (i assume based on your tag) the oauth flow that is used is the  [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-dev-understanding-oauth2-implicit-grant), where redirect uri is not involved.

Look at this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android sample on how ot integrate android client with Azure AD.

Comment: No,Here i am asking for handle response of Redirect Uri.If i am not wrong here use of redirect url is to get access token so i am using my custom url or api to get access token,but i don't know how to handle this in android code.How can i get token from my api.How to write code for this?